# Remove part of string in between two specific characters in perl

Tags: perl

Like for example 
"Neuer Termin mit ihn am Mittwoch {$tag._value="weekday=wednesday"} um 2{$tag._value="02"}"
is my string and i want 
"Neuer Termin mit ihn am Mittwoch um 2".
as "{$tag._value="weekday=wednesday"}" and "{$tag._value="02"}" can change so the lenght is not constant i want to remove it on basis like "{$tag._value="weekday=wednesday"}" remove everything that comes between { } but do not remove anything outside {}.

Comment: No one can understand what you're asking

Comment: @choroba: Please don't replace the question with your speculations.

Answer (score 2):

I understand your question as *"How do I remove everything between `{` and `}`?"*

This will do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = 'Neuer Termin mit ihn am Mittwoch {$tag._value="weekday=wednesday"} um 2{$tag._value="02"}';
$string =~ s/\{[^\}]+\}//g;
print "'$string'\n";
```

**Output**

```
'Neuer Termin mit ihn am Mittwoch  um 2'
```

---

By the way: it should be either

> Neuer Termin mit **Ihnen** am Mittwoch (new appointment with **you** on/next wednesday)

or

> Neuer Termin mit **ihm** am Mittwoch (new appointment with **him** on/next wednesday)

Answer (score 0):

You say

`"Neuer Termin mit ihn am Mittwoch {$tag._value="weekday=wednesday"} um 2{$tag._value="02"}"` is my string

But you have double quotes `"` within the string. You need to explain your problem better: where does this string come from?

For non-German speakers, *"Neuer Termin mit ihn am Mittwoch"* is something like *"New appointment with him mid-week"*

Answer (score -1):

> In this case you have only open and close then this will remove the pattern of brackets

```
#For the testing purpose we escaped the double quotes within the string.
my $string = "Neuer Termin mit ihn am Mittwoch {$tag._value=\"weekday=wednesday\"} um 2{$tag._value=\"02\"}";

$string=~s/\{([^\{\}]*)\}//g;

print $string;
```

> In case if you have nested brackets you can use. `{{{}}}`

```
$CurBrLoopMany = qw/((?:[^{}]*(?:{(?:[^{}]*(?:{(?:[^{}]*(?:{[^{}]*})*[^{}]*)*})*[^{}]*)*})*[^{}]*)*)/;

$string=~s/\{$CurBrLoopMany\}//g;

print $string;
```

Comment: It's unhelpful to post speculative answers. You're assuming too much here.

Comment: Your suggestion for `$CurBrLoopMany` is bizarre!

Comment: Might be I am not very well in English language however `remove everything that comes between { } but do not remove anything outside {}.` OP asking this only right?

Comment: `bizarre` whatever I am using in my code. If this may be simplified/alternative solutions I can be updated in my code

Comment: I'm sure that you have copied that regex pattern from somewhere else. Do you know what it does? I am far from sure, but it seems to match nested braces to a specific level. It certainly needs a comment to explain its function.

Comment: Absolutely, Its my seniors `Ancestors` already developed codes which I have working right now also I don't know its right or wrong but that tools are working.

Comment: @Borodin: What about your opinion/suggestion/comments on PerlDuck's answers

Answer (score -3):

This will modify $string to the result you want to have.

```
 $string =~ s/\{.*?\}//g;
```

Comment: Explain yourself please.